# Issue with constant re-rendering on React array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am developing a React Component which holds an object, in the following format:

```
{
  data: [{item1}, {item2}, ..., {item10}],
  filters: { ...filterOptions },
}
```

The parent Components `render` function basically maps the `data` into another Component called `ItemSelector`. The `ItemSelector` then checks the item type and render the specific `Item`.

I implemented a pagination feature that will update the `data` key with a new Array (by a new Array I mean I am updating the `reducer` attribute using `immutability-helper` with `$set` operation). Although the Array is a new object, `{item1}, {item2}, ..., {item10}` are always the same objects, but now the Array goes from `{item1}` to `{item20}` instead.

The issue I am facing is that I can't avoid the re-rendering for the items that were already on the Array, wasting computation on items that were already rendered. I tried setting a unique key for `ItemSelector` and removing the `ItemSelector` from the parent Component and calling the specific `Item` components directly with a unique key, but it didn't solve the issue.

Is there any way I can prevent re-rendering the `Item` Components when it is already rendered?

Comment: You could try making `Item` extend [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) instead of `Component` and see if that helps, as long as you are immutably updating your state.

Comment: @Tholle I tried doing it, but `Item` keeps re-rendering. I understand that it would make prevent the re-rendering if the Array didn't change its size (as demonstrated [here](https://codeburst.io/react-array-re-render-performance-ee23f34c5d66?gi=7f5197a99185)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to solve this in some cases.

[Simple example @ codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbdRmV)

```
const Item = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log(`${props.title} rendered`); // check browser console
  return <li>{props.title}</li>;
});
```

But it says in the docu:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.